# spark out of memory error

Tags: apache-spark, out-of-memory

My spark program work well on small data set.(about 400GB)
However when I extend it to large data set. I begin to get error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` or `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit`

My program is like this:
sc.textFile  ->  map  -> filter -> groupBy  -> saveAsObjectFile

`groupBy` generate result with type   RDD[ (int,Iteratable[A] )  ]

The error occurs a `saveAsObjectFile`.
The only reason I can think of is that :
   at `groupBy`  step some keys contains too large data.
However I checked all key with `Hive`, the largest one is 330808.
class A is also not very large.

My configuration is:
-driver-memory 20G --num-executors 120 --executor-memory 30G
Spark version: 1.4

```
15/07/03 07:05:06 ERROR ActorSystemImpl: Uncaught fatal error from thread 
[sparkDriver-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-5] shutting down ActorSystem [sparkDriver]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2271)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:113)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:140)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1876)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1785)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1188)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
        at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer$$anonfun$toBinary$1.apply$mcV$sp(Serializer.scala:129)
        at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer$$anonfun$toBinary$1.apply(Serializer.scala:129)
        at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer$$anonfun$toBinary$1.apply(Serializer.scala:129)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer.toBinary(Serializer.scala:129)
        at akka.remote.MessageSerializer$.serialize(MessageSerializer.scala:36)
        at akka.remote.EndpointWriter$$anonfun$serializeMessage$1.apply(Endpoint.scala:845)
        at akka.remote.EndpointWriter$$anonfun$serializeMessage$1.apply(Endpoint.scala:845)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at akka.remote.EndpointWriter.serializeMessage(Endpoint.scala:844)
        at akka.remote.EndpointWriter.writeSend(Endpoint.scala:747)
        at akka.remote.EndpointWriter$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(Endpoint.scala:722)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
        at akka.remote.EndpointActor.aroundReceive(Endpoint.scala:415)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
```

Comment: is this error message from driver or executor?

Comment: @VijayInnamuri Question updated. seems from driver.

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution for the driver OutOfMemory is to increase the driver memory using “spark.driver.memory” property.

Below article might help in memory allocation for driver and executors
http://www.wdong.org/wordpress/blog/2015/01/08/spark-on-yarn-where-have-all-my-memory-gone/

Also note that 
`GroupByKey` is costlier operation. So try to avoid it and use reduceByKey.

http://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html

Comment: BUT in which step could lead to such huge memory. I have already given it 20G

Answer (score 1):

Your job is probably not balanced so that a few partitions get a lot of the keys (and their values). You can try adding more partitions and/or writing a custom partitioner that evens out the partitions based on your knowledge of the data