# Pyspark java.lang.OutOfMemoryError error with wholeTextFiles

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have 1160 XML files, each of size 300MB in the `data_dir`. I want to count the number of whole words. I have a local machine with 256 cores and 256 GB RAM. Given that the whole data size is around 300GB, I know I likely cannot process all the files at once. I am wondering how can I do batch processing or partitioning to avoid the `java. lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error? This is my code:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data_dir = '/shared/hm31/xml_data/'

   

    conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("WordCount")
    conf.set("spark.driver.memory", "200g")
    conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "6g")  # Example: Increase executor memory

    sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

    rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles(data_dir,500)
    words = rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x.split())
    print("words",words.count())
```

Update:
Even after I use 200GB RAM and 3 CPUs, I still get out of memory error.

This is my code:

```
data_dir = '/shared/hm31/xml_data/'




conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[3]").setAppName("WordCount")
conf.set("spark.driver.memory", "200g")


sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles(data_dir,512)
words = rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x.split())
print("Words",words.count())
```

And this is the error I get:

```
23/10/03 13:24:28 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread stdout writer for python3
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3745)
        at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:120)
        at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:95)
        at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:156)
        at org.sparkproject.guava.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:211)
        at org.sparkproject.guava.io.ByteStreams.toByteArray(ByteStreams.java:252)
        at org.apache.spark.input.WholeTextFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(WholeTextFileRecordReader.scala:79)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(CombineFileRecordReader.java:65)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:307)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:729)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:435)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$Lambda$1407/0x000000084089c040.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2048)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:270)
Exception in thread "stdout writer for python3" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3745)
        at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:120)
        at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:95)
        at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:156)
        at org.sparkproject.guava.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:211)
        at org.sparkproject.guava.io.ByteStreams.toByteArray(ByteStreams.java:252)
        at org.apache.spark.input.WholeTextFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(WholeTextFileRecordReader.scala:79)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(CombineFileRecordReader.java:65)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:307)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:729)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:435)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$Lambda$1407/0x000000084089c040.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2048)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:270)
23/10/03 13:24:28 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread stdout writer for python3
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3745)
        at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:120)
        at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:95)
        at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:156)
        at org.sparkproject.guava.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:211)
        at org.sparkproject.guava.io.ByteStreams.toByteArray(ByteStreams.java:252)
        at org.apache.spark.input.WholeTextFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(WholeTextFileRecordReader.scala:79)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(CombineFileRecordReader.java:65)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:307)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:729)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:435)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$Lambda$1407/0x000000084089c040.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2048)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:270)
Exception in thread "stdout writer for python3" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3745)
        at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:120)
        at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:95)
        at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:156)
        at org.sparkproject.guava.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:211)
        at org.sparkproject.guava.io.ByteStreams.toByteArray(ByteStreams.java:252)
        at org.apache.spark.input.WholeTextFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(WholeTextFileRecordReader.scala:79)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(CombineFileRecordReader.java:65)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:307)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:729)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:435)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$Lambda$1407/0x000000084089c040.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2048)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:270)
23/10/03 13:24:29 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread stdout writer for python3
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "stdout writer for python3" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep it simple, you can do the following steps in order:

1. You're trying to set the `spark.driver.memory` configuration after your application has already started up. This is not possible. You should set this parameter in the command start starts your application. For example: `pyspark --driver-memory 200g ...` or `spark-submit --driver-memory 200g ...`. Without this you're just running with the default 1g for memory.
2. You're using `.setMaster("local[*]")`, which means you're running spark in local mode. In this case, `spark.executor.memory` is ignored. So:

   - remove `spark.executor.memory`
   - make `spark.driver.memory` as large as possible (something like `240g`, dependent on other processes running on your machine)
3. If you're still getting your out of memory errors after the previous steps, it means that for your workload, you don't have enough RAM/cpu. This is wholly dependent of your data (and the biggest files in there). In that case, you can lower the amount of number of CPU that are running, and have more RAM/cpu. For example, if you want to limit your calculation to use 128 CPU (instead of `[*]` which means all CPU available), you can do the following:

```
.setMaster("local[128]")
```

Comment: Thank you. I did step 1 with 200g which was my free memory, still got the same error. I reduced the number of cores to 10 or 2, but strangely still got that error

Comment: Ooh that's interesting. Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77219454/edit) your question and add the full java error stack trace? It should look something like the multiple lines of error message you see in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31199051/spark-out-of-memory-error) post.

Comment: Ahhhh I I've adapted my answer, something really important flew over my head. Hope that solves your issue!

Comment: Thanks. It solved my issue! The only matter I had to solve was that the output of wholeTextFiles is a tuple so I needed to do     contents = rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x[1].split('\n'))